# Rewrite an equation by deriving the Schrondinger eigenvalue equation (linear momentum)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, momentum, schroedinger-equation, klein-gordon-equation

I want to rewrite the equation as follows:

$$\frac{\partial^2\psi(x,t)}{\partial x^2}=-\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\bigg)^2\psi(x,t)$$

The initial equation is as follows:

$$-i\frac{h}{2\pi}\frac{\partial \psi(x,t)}{\partial x}=p\,\psi(x,t)$$

How can I get to the equation: $\frac{\partial^2\psi(x,t)}{\partial x^2}=-\big(\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\big)^2\psi(x,t)$, starting from the initial equation?

I don't know how I can derive the initial equation in order to x, because I don't know what the derivative of $\psi(x,t)$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you do - rearranging the "initial" equation you've provided gives
$$\frac{\partial\psi(x,t)}{\partial x} = \frac{2\pi i p}{h}\psi(x,t)$$

Differentiating again gives you just what you're looking for - assuming that you are familiar with the concept of the [de Broglie wavelength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave) of a particle.

Comment: I still can not vote for your answer, but thank you, now I realized the reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

You do! that's the initial equation that you have!
$$-i \bigg(\frac{h}{2 \pi }\bigg)\frac{\partial \psi(x,t)}{\partial x} = p \psi(x,t)$$ So if you differentiate the equation again you get,
$$-i \frac{h}{2 \pi }\frac{\partial^2 \psi(x,t)}{\partial x^2} = p \frac{\partial \psi(x,t)}{\partial x} = i p^2 \frac{2 \pi}{h} \psi(x,t) $$ The expression for the debroglie wavelength is, $\lambda = \frac{h}{p}$. So, we get,
$$\frac{\partial^2 \psi(x,t)}{\partial x^2} = - \bigg(\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\bigg)^2  \psi(x,t)$$
Which is the desired answer.

Comment: Why does the derivative of $\psi(x,t)$ give $ip\frac{2\pi}{h}$?

Comment: @MariaBarroso Oh, it was the initial equation that Aaron had written, But I think the assumption here is that $\psi(x,t)$ is a momentum eigenstate since the momentum operator  $\hat{P} = - i \hslash \frac{\partial }{\partial x}$

Comment: I don't think I wrote any equations

Comment: @AaronStevens I don't quite understand. You wrote, "the equation goes ..."

Comment: You do realize that I didn't write this question, right?

Comment: @AaronStevens I'm sorry, but could you explain what you mean? You wrote the initial equation in your question, did you not?

Comment: I did not write this question. @MariaBarroso did

Comment: @AaronStevens I'm sorry! I misread it. It was definitely Maria who wrote it!